# How to pass Hashmap to another class(different package) when it is declared with default specifier in Java

Tags: java, hashmap, parameter-passing

There was an SDET coding challenge from Hacker Rank.

**Structure**

[image]

**Class DataEntryAutomationTest**

```
public class DataEntryAutomationTest {

private static WebDriver driver = null;
private static String pagUrl = null;

static Map<String, String> data = null;

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@BeforeClass
public static void setup() {  //code for initializing driver.         
    data = new HashMap() {
        {
            put("11", "day");
            put("July", "month");
            put("1990", "year");
            put("favorite_language", "Java,Python");
            put("favorite_os", "Linux,Mac OSX");
            put("favorite_idea", "IntelliJ IDEA");
        }
    };

    pagUrl = "http://localhost:8080/home.html";
}

 @Test
    public void testFillDateOfBirth() {
       DataEntryAutomation.fillDateOfBirth(driver, pagUrl);
 }

 @Test
    public void testAnswerQuestions() {
       DataEntryAutomation.answerQuestions(driver, pagUrl);
 }
```

**Class DataEntryAutomation**

```
public class DataEntryAutomation {

    public static void fillDateOfBirth(WebDriver driver, String pageUrl) {
       //add code to fill the survey
}


public static void answerQuestions(WebDriver driver, String pageUrl) {
     //add code to fill the survey
}
```

How do I pass the HashMap to **DataEntryAutomation Class** so that I can use the HashMap to fill the survey.
My understanding is If modifier is not mentioned then the default access specifier is package. Classes can access the members of other classes in the same package but outside the package it appears as private.
Limitation :
**I can only edit DataEntryAutomation Class**

Comment: This is test-driven development. You shouldn't be passing the map in the test class to the main class. You have to implement the methods in `DataEntryAutomation` such that the test class passes.

Comment: @WilliamBurnham, I haven't worked on test-driven development. Will surely look into it. But the methods mentioned in DataEntryAutomation Class need the data (ex. select values for dropdowns which are mentioned in BeforeClass). Can you explain a bit on that?